# Codeigniter - Update database function not working (Trying to edit profile)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a page where users can change their user account info and it will update that from the database. The database tables are not affected. Nothing happens. It wont even show me form validation like "Error: This field is required" or "error: please enter a valid email"

I cannot get this to work because I'm getting 3 errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Use of undefined constant FLASE - assumed 'FLASE'
>
> Filename: controllers/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 45

And

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Profile::$model_profile
>
> Filename: controllers/profile.php
>
> Line Number: 52

And finally

> Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dayone/application/controllers/profile.php on line 52

My profile.php controller:

```
public function update_profile()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //rules to become a registered user

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|min_length[3]|max_length[20]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FLASE) {
        //user didin't validate, send back to login form
        $this->load->view('profile/includes/header');
        $this->load->view('profile/profile_settings');
    }
    else {

        $result = $this->model_profile->update();
        //successful update

        if ($result) {
            //$this->load->view
            $this->load->view('profile/includes/header');
        $this->load->view('profile/profile_body');
        }
    }

}
```

My form page where users edit their info:

```
<!-- Forms -->
            <?php
           $attributes = array('class' => 'pi-row pi-grid-small-margin', 'id' => 'contact-form');
            echo form_open('profile/update_profile', $attributes); 
            ?>


                <div class="pi-row pi-grid-small-margins">

                    <!-- Col 6 -->
                    <div class="pi-col-sm-6">

                        <!-- First name form -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name">First name</label>

                            <div class="pi-input-with-icon">
                                <div class="pi-input-icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>"; class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="<?php echo $first_name;?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End first name form -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- End col 6 -->

                    <!-- Col 6 -->
                    <div class="pi-col-sm-6">
                    <!-- Last name form -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="last_name">Last name</label>

                            <div class="pi-input-with-icon">
                                <div class="pi-input-icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="<?php echo $last_name;?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Last name form -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- End col 6 -->

                </div>


                <!-- Email form -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName-3">Email Address</label>

                    <div class="pi-input-with-icon">
                        <div class="pi-input-icon"><i class="icon-mail"></i></div>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="value="<?php echo $email;?>"">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Email form -->

                <!-- Username form -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputCompanyname-3">Username <font color="#aca3a3"> (Cannot be changed)</font></label>

                    <div class="pi-input-with-icon">
                        <div class="pi-input-icon"><i class="icon-users"></i></div>
                        <input type="text" disabled name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username;?>" id="username" placeholder="<?php echo $username;?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Username form -->


                <hr class="pi-divider-gap-10">

                <!-- Submit button -->
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn pi-btn-green">
                        <i class="icon-pencil pi-icon-left"></i>Save
                    </button>
                   <!-- Button to cancel -->
                    <a class="btn pi-btn-red icon-cancel pi-icon-left" href="<?php echo base_url();?>profile">Cancel</a>
                <!-- End submit button -->

             <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And finally, my `model_profile.php` model:

```
    public function update() {


    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET first_name = '{$first_name}', last_name = '{$last_name}', email = '{$email}' WHERE uid = $uid LIMIT 1";
    $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `FLASE` => `FALSE` - Isn't the warning obvious?

Answer (score 1):

1st error, you have a typo:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FLASE)
```

Instead of

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

2nd and 3rd errors, you have to load the model before using it :

```
$this->load->model("model_profile");
$result = $this->model_profile->update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the modal function like this

```
       $this->load->model('model_profile');
       $this->model_profile->update;
```